# "lower bound" in Scala understanding

Tags: scala

I am trying to understand "lower bound" in scala. Please find the below example

```
class  Animal
class Dog extends Animal
class Puppy extends Dog
class Human extends Animal
class Plant
class AnimalDisplay{
  def displayUptoDog [T >: Dog](t: T){
    println(t)
  }

  def displayUptoAnimal [T >: Animal](t: T){
    println(">>"+t.getClass())
  } 

}

object ScalaLowerBoundsTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {     
    val animal = new Animal
    val dog = new Dog
    val puppy = new Puppy
    val human=new Human
    val plant = new Plant
    val animalDisplay = new AnimalDisplay

     println("Upto Animal")
    animalDisplay.displayUptoAnimal(animal)
    animalDisplay.displayUptoAnimal(dog)
    animalDisplay.displayUptoAnimal(puppy)
    animalDisplay.displayUptoAnimal(human)
    animalDisplay.displayUptoAnimal(plant) 

 println("Upto Dog")
    animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(animal)    
    animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(dog)
    animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(puppy)
// prints: com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Puppy@1b6d3586
    animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(human)
//print:com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Human@4554617c
    animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(plant)
//prints:com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Plant@74a14482
  }
}
```

My questions are

1. As Puppy is not a Dog as well as not a super class of Dog, then
       why  `animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(puppy)` is allowed? some real
       usecase will help me to understand better
2. If it`(animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(puppy))`  is allowed then it
   should
           print `com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Dog@xxxxx` instead of
           `com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Puppy@1b6d3586`
3. animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(human) where Human is not a super class
   of Dog then why it is allowed and printing
   "com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Human@4554617c"
4. animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(plant) where Plant is not in the same
   hierarchy, then why it is also allowed and printing
   "com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Plant@74a14482"

Let me know if I am missing some thing

Comment: `com.typeSystem.typeBound.lowerBound.Puppy` is the runtime class. It doesn't say anything about the compile time type. You can use a `TypeTag` for information about the compile time type.

Answer (score 0):

`animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(puppy)` is allowed, because you can cast `Puppy` to a `Dog`, like this:

```scala
animalDisplay.displayUptoDog(puppy: Dog)
```

Now you may ask, what is the point of using lower bounds on `T` in method signatures, if you can simply upcast the object to `T` so it fits? To answer that question, I think it's best to look at an example, where lower bounds are indeed useful or even necessary.

One very common use case for lower bounds is when you would like to ensure that some method returns a value of type that is common with some other type, for instance in `Option[A]` there is a method:

```scala
def getOrElse[B >: A](default: ⇒ B): B
```

If we want it the type that is common for `A` and `B`, the only reasonable option is when `A` is a subtype of `B`. In opposite case (`B <: A`), you couldn't return `A` if that option was a `Some[A]` because `A` is not a subtype of `B`.

Here is an example how it works when we apply it to the `Dog` class hierarchy:

```scala
val d1 = Some(dog).getOrElse(puppy) 
d1: Dog = $sess.cmd1$Dog@55e02661

val d2 = (None: Option[Dog]).getOrElse(puppy) 
d2: Dog = $sess.cmd2$Puppy@420068a

val d3 = Some(puppy).getOrElse(dog) 
d3: Dog = $sess.cmd2$Puppy@420068a

val d4 = (None: Option[Puppy]).getOrElse(dog) 
d4: Dog = $sess.cmd1$Dog@55e02661
```

As you can see in all cases it behaves as expected. Calling `getOrElse` when `A` and `B` are either `Dog` or `Puppy` always returns a type that common for both of them which is `Dog`.